# Stripping URLs in regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to isolate the domain name for a database full of URLs, but I'm running into some regex problems.

Starting example:

```
examples = ['www2.chccs.k12.nc.us', 'wwwsco.com', 'www-152.aig.com', 'www.google.com']
```

Desired goal:

```
['chccs.k12.nc.us', 'sco.com', 'aig.com', 'google.com']
```

I've been trying a two stage process where I add in a *"."* before *"www"*, then replace the *"www."*, but that doesn't quite lead to the results I'd like.

Any regex wizards out there able to help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those are all domain names. What's your criteria for "domain" ?

Comment: Try this for the regex `www[\w\d-]*\.`, Except for `wwwsco.com`, it should work for all the rest, as it should match everything after the first `.` if you use `re.sub`.

Comment: @tdelaney thanks for correcting my language, sorry I'm not sure what the right terminology is. By domain in this context I meant the main part of the url, without any www beforehand. Is there a specific name for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

def extract(domain):
    return re.sub(r'^www[\d-]*\.?', '', domain)

examples = ['www2.chccs.k12.nc.us', 'wwwsco.com', 'www-152.aig.com', 'www.google.com']
result = [extract(d) for d in examples]
assert result == ['chccs.k12.nc.us', 'sco.com', 'aig.com', 'google.com'], result
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate the help.